# how to filter the first date and the time

Tags: excel, sorting, date

I have the date cell where the values are "30/Jun/2020 11:36 30/Jun/2020 11:40 M L", I want to extract only the first date and time "30/Jun/2020 11:36" in Excel.
Can someone help me how to do this in excel.

**Current output**

```
30/Jun/2020 11:36 30/Jun/2020 11:40 M L
```

**Expected output**

```
30/Jun/2020 11:36
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FILTERXML()` may work for you in this case. Try-

```
=TEXT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>",2)&"</s></t>","//s[1]"),"dd/mmm/yyyy hh:mm")
```

You can also use-

```
=LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)+1)-1)
```

Above formula will return result as text string. If you want to return result as date format then use

```
=TEXT(LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)+1)-1)*1, "dd/mmm/yyyy hh:mm")
```

[image]

Comment: How to bring the character "T" between the date and time after the above formula applied, like "21/Sep/2020T08:07"

Comment: Use `T` in format like `dd/mmm/yyyyThh:mm`.